# dynamic_partition with dynamic num_partitions

Tags: tensorflow

The variable `num_partitions` in the method `tf.dynamic_partition` is not a `Tensor`, but an `int`. 
Therefore, if the number of partitions isn't known in advance, it can't be inferred from the data by e.g., counting the number of unique values nor can't be given by a `tf.placeholder`.
How can one use this method in such a dynamic scenario?

If it's impossible, a plausible workaround is to set the value of this parameter to some upper bound. Then at running time there will be some empty lists. The question is how those empty lists can be eliminated?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the harm in passing a integer to your class which is building the model? You can have an `edit_partitions()` function in your class or something

Comment: Note that output of `tf.dynamic_partition` is a Python list. So you could make sure empty tensors are always at the end and use Python list indexing to chop off the tail. You may need to split it into two `sess.run` calls in order to get the length into Python-land.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have fully dynamic partition you could have an op that returns a single Tensor with dynamic shape rather than Python-time fixed number of tensors, but the problem is that tensor dimensions must be rectangular and your partitions could have different lengths. To work-around it you might encode your variable size lists into strings which have shape () or use `TensorArray`. Here's a way to do it by using png encoding for arrays<=>string conversion

```
def dynamic_partition_png(vals, idx, max_partitions):
    """Encodes output of dynamic partition as a Tensor of png-encoded strings."""
    max_idx = tf.reduce_max(idx)
    max_vals = tf.reduce_max(idx)
    with tf.control_dependencies([tf.Assert(max_vals<256, ["vals must be <256"])]):
        outputs = tf.dynamic_partition(vals, idx, num_partitions=max_partitions)
    png_outputs = []
    dummy_png = tf.image.encode_png(([[[2]]]))
    not_empty_ops = [] # ops that detect empty lists that aren't at the end
    for i, o in enumerate(outputs):
        reshaped_o = tf.reshape(tf.cast(o, tf.uint8), [-1, 1, 1])
        png_output = tf.cond(tf.size(reshaped_o)>0, lambda: tf.image.encode_png(reshaped_o), lambda: dummy_png)
        png_outputs.append(png_output)
        not_empty_ops.append(tf.logical_or(i>max_idx, tf.size(reshaped_o)>0))
    packed_tensor = tf.pack(png_outputs)
    no_illegal_empty_lists = tf.reduce_all(tf.pack(not_empty_ops))
    with tf.control_dependencies([tf.Assert(no_illegal_empty_lists, ["empty lists must be last"])]):
        result = packed_tensor[:max_idx+1]
    return result

def decode(p):
    return tf.image.decode_png(p)[:, 0, 0]

sess = tf.Session()
vals = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5])
idx = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
tf_vals = dynamic_partition_png(vals, idx, 3)
print(sess.run(decode(tf_vals[0]))) # => [1 2]
print(sess.run(decode(tf_vals[1]))) # => [3 4 5]
print(sess.run(decode(tf_vals[2]))) # => slice index 2 of dimension 0 out of bounds
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do this. The trick is, we know `tf.dynamic_partition` does not accept int tensors but `tf.slice` does! so why not slice after doing partition over some maximum interger.

```
def get_parameter_vectors(parameter_vector, nb_dimensions, nb_parameters):
    """
    Returns an unpacked list of parameters vectors.
    https://towardsdatascience.com/a-hitchhikers-guide-to-mixture-density-networks-76b435826cca
    """
    return [parameter_vector[:, i * nb_dimensions:(i + 1) * nb_dimensions] for i in range(nb_parameters)]

def binary_crossentropy(y):
    y_true = y[:, 0:1]
    y_pred = y[:, 1:2]
    return binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

def vectorized_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):

    y_true, date_ = get_parameter_vectors(y_true, 1, 2)
     
    batch_size = 128 # ofcourse your unique's will not exceed this number, so this is safe maximum to use

    unique_dates, partitions = tf.unique(date_)
    y_elements = tf.dynamic_partition(tf.concat([y_true, y_pred], axis=1), partitions, num_partitions=batch_size)
    y_elements = tf.ragged.stack(y_elements).to_tensor(shape=[None, batch_size, 2])  # there will be zeros padded to make it same size 
    y_elements = tf.slice(y_elements, [0, 0, 0], [tf.size(unique_dates), y_elements.shape[1], y_elements.shape[2]])  # you need to cut those zero 

    result = tf.vectorized_map(binary_crossentropy, y_elements)
    
    # you just calculated one binary_crossentropy loss per date HURRAY!!!
```