# How to feed a TensorArray to a TensorFlow session

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow

One of the inputs to my TensorFlow graph is an list of variable-length arrays (e.g. `[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]`). To represent this, I've used TensorArray in the graph.

However, when it comes to running the graph, I can't find a way to feed in a batch of the TensorArrays, as `feed_dict={ some_ta: [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]] }` doesn't work.

Is there currently any workaround that allows me to directly input TensorArrays into a session?

Answer (score 0):

There's no out-of-the-box solution for this case, but you can try a workaround.

1. The simplest workaround is to pad all of your input data (for example with zeros) so that all arrays have the same dimension. Note that tensorflow is designed to perform calculations with *tensors*, which have rectangular, not variable, shape. As a result, this way your operations are likely to be done much faster, but you need to adapt the algorithm to ignore trailing zeros.

   In the example above, the code is simple:

   ```
   # can hold any number of 4-D vectors
   input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 4])
   with tf.Session() as session:
     data = [[0, 1, 2, 0], [3, 4, 0, 0], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
     print session.run(input, feed_dict={input: data})
   ```
2. If the lengths happen to be fixed, you can partition the input this way

   ```
   input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None])
   split = tf.dynamic_partition(input, partitions=[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], num_partitions=3)

   with tf.Session() as session:
     data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
     print session.run(split, feed_dict={input: data})
   ```

   The result is the following:

   ```
   [array([ 0.,  1.,  2.], dtype=float32), array([ 3.,  4.], dtype=float32), array([ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.], dtype=float32)]
   ```

   The `partitions` parameter can't be a tensor, so it must be known statically when the graph is built.
3. To perform a truly arbitrary split, you're going to do this manually yourself. You still pass the `data` as a single array, along with `partitions` holding the partition indices. Then you can perform a tedious split as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46267278/712995) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41408561/712995). I wouldn't recommend you follow this path unless there's absolutely no other way.