# Organizing tensor into batches of dynamically shaped tensors

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have the following situation:

- I want to deploy a face detector model using Tensorflow Serving: https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/.
- In Tensorflow Serving, there is a command line option called `--enable_batching`. This causes the model server to automatically batch the requests to maximize throughput. I want this to be enabled.
- My model takes in a set of images (called **images**), which is a tensor of shape `(batch_size, 640, 480, 3)`.
- The model has two outputs: `(number_of_faces, 4)` and `(number_of_faces,)`. The first output will be called **faces**. The last output, which we can call **partitions** is the index in the original batch for the corresponding face. For example, if I pass in a batch of 4 **images** and get 7 **faces**, then I might have this tensor as `[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]`. The first two faces correspond to the first image, the third face for the second image, the 3rd image has 3 faces, etc.

My issue is this:

- In order for the `--enable_batching` flag to work, the output from my model needs to have the 0th dimension the same as the input. That is, I need a tensor with the following shape: `(batch_size, ...)`. I suppose this is so that the model server can know which grpc connection to send each output in the batch towards.
- What I want to do is to convert my output tensor from the face detector from this shape `(number_of_faces, 4)` to this shape `(batch_size, None, 4)`. That is, an array of batches, where each batch can have a variable number of faces (e.g. one image in the batch may have no faces, and another might have 3).

What I tried:

- `tf.dynamic_partition`. On the surface, this function looks perfect. However, I ran into difficulties after realizing that the `num_partitions` parameter *cannot* be a tensor, only an integer:

  `tensorflow_serving_output = tf.dynamic_partition(faces, partitions, batch_size)`

If the `tf.dynamic_partition` function were to accept tensor values for `num_partition`, then it seems that my problem would be solved. However, I am back to square one since this is not the case.

Thank you all for your help! Let me know if anything is unclear

P.S. Here is a visual representation of the intended process:

[image: Image batch to prediction batch]

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding a solution to this using `TensorArray` and `tf.while_loop`:

```
def batch_reconstructor(tensor, partitions, batch_size):
    """
    Take a tensor of shape (batch_size, 4) and a 1-D partitions tensor as well as the scalar batch_size
    And reconstruct a TensorArray that preserves the original batching

    From the partitions, we can get the maximum amount of tensors within a batch. This will inform the padding we need to use.
    Params:
        - tensor: The tensor to convert to a batch
        - partitions: A list of batch indices. The tensor at position i corresponds to batch # partitions[i]
    """
    tfarr = tf.TensorArray(tf.int32, size=batch_size, infer_shape=False)

    _, _, count = tf.unique_with_counts(partitions)
    maximum_tensor_size = tf.cast(tf.reduce_max(count), tf.int32)

    padding_tensor_index = tf.cast(tf.gather(tf.shape(tensor), 0), tf.int32)

    padding_tensor = tf.expand_dims(tf.cast(tf.fill([4], -1), tf.float32), axis=0) # fill with [-1, -1, -1, -1]
    tensor = tf.concat([tensor, padding_tensor], axis=0)

    def cond(i, acc):
        return tf.less(i, batch_size)

    def body(i, acc):
        partition_indices = tf.reshape(tf.cast(tf.where(tf.equal(partitions, i)), tf.int32), [-1])

        partition_size = tf.gather(tf.shape(partition_indices), 0)

        # concat the partition_indices with padding_size * padding_tensor_index
        padding_size = tf.subtract(maximum_tensor_size, partition_size)
        padding_indices = tf.reshape(tf.fill([padding_size], padding_tensor_index), [-1])

        partition_indices = tf.concat([partition_indices, padding_indices], axis=0)

        return (tf.add(i, 1), acc.write(i, tf.gather(tensor, partition_indices)))

    _, reconstructed = tf.while_loop(
        cond,
        body,
        (tf.constant(0), tfarr),
        name='batch_reconstructor'
    )

    reconstructed = reconstructed.stack()
    return reconstructed
```

Comment: Hello, do you think the above issues is somehow related to this github issue also.
I am kind of stuck at certain area where I am trying some experiments.
https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/2043